# How to do ExecuteScalar Function with Npgsql and PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net, npgsql

I am learning Npgsql and PostgrSQL.  I am unable to get this simple test to work.  Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_customers(_customerid integer DEFAULT NULL::integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerId = _customerid or _customerid is null;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Here is my C# code:

```
[Test]
public void ExecuteScalarTest()
{
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=localhost; Database=postgres; User ID=postgres; Password=password");
    conn.Open();
    IDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "count_customers";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

I keep getting the error below.
***Npgsql.NpgsqlException : ERROR: 42601: query has no destination for result data***

Comment: +1 thanks for showing your code and the exact error message text. In future, PostgreSQL version is always preferred too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with nPgSQL. Your problem is in your stored function.

You've written a trivial wrapper in PL/PgSQL, but you haven't used `RETURN`. You can't use `SELECT` in PL/PgSQL except when its output goes to a variable (via `SELECT INTO` or as a subquery like `x := (SELECT ...)` or to the `RETURN QUERY` statement.

You should write:

```
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers 
    WHERE CustomerId = _customerid
       OR _customerid is null;
END
```

and define your procedure as `RETURNS bigint`, since obviously you cannot get a value from the function if it returns `void`. Also, this function is `STABLE` not `VOLATILE`. If you aren't sure, say nothing. The same is true for `COST`  - unless you have a good reason, leave it out.

This is still overcomplicated though. You can use a simple sql function for calls like this, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_customers(_customerid integer DEFAULT NULL::integer)
RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$BODY$
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerId = $1 OR $1 is null;
$BODY$;
```